# gitlab-ci: provide environment variable(s) to custom docker image in a pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to set up a test stage for my gitlab-ci which depends on a custom docker image. I want to know how will I provide some config (like setting env variable to providing a .env file) to it so that the custom image runs properly and hence the stage.
Current config:

```
test_job:
  only:
  refs:
    - master
    - merge_requests
    - web
stage: test
services:
  - mongo:4.0.4
  - redis:5.0.1
  - registry.gitlab.com/myteam/myprivaterepo:latest 
variables:
  - PORT=3000
  - SERVER_HOST=myprivaterepo
  - SERVER_PORT=9090
script: npm test
```

I want to provide environment variables to `myprivaterepo` docker image which connects to `mongo:4.0.4` and `redis:5.0.1` services for its functioning.

**EDIT:** The variables are `MONGODB_URI="mongodb://mongo:27017/aics"` and `REDIS_CLIENT_HOST: "redis"`. These have no meaning for the app being tested but has meaning for the `myprivaterepo` image without which the test stage will fail.

Comment: Can you provide an example for such an environment variable?  
What would you want do achieve with this variable?

Comment: Okay. I've updated the question.

Comment: what about :
`before_script:`
`- export MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/aics` ?

Comment: @RuslanLópez I am pretty sure that docker doesn't automatically take in env variables into its running containers from host. And I want to provide these env variables specifically to `myprivaterepo` image so that when the container is running, it works as expected.

Comment: That's the way we set environment variables such as Java_HOME

Comment: Are you sure that the variable is accessible to the services running?

Comment: This is actually a feature request for gitlab ci - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/50248. Hope they implement it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It is as simple as adding the environment variables in the `variables:` part of the yaml. This is what worked for me:-

```
test_job:
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - merge_requests
      - web

    stage: test

    services:
      - mongo:4.0.4
      - redis:5.0.1
      - name: registry.gitlab.com/myteam/myprivaterepo:latest
        alias: myprivaterepo

    variables:
      - MYPRIVATEREPO_PORT: 9090 # Had to modify image to use this variable
      - MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/aics
      - REDIS_CLIENT_HOST: redis
      - PORT: 3000 # for app being tested
      - SERVER_HOST: myprivaterepo
      - SERVER_PORT: 9090

    script: npm test
```

These variables seeem to be applied to all services.

**NOTE**: There is a catch - you *cannot* use 2 images using same environment variable names.

Like, I initially used `PORT=????` as environment variables in both `myprivaterepo` and this app being tested so an error would pop up saying `EADDRINUSE`. So I had to update `myprivaterepo` to use `MYPRIVATEREPO_PORT`

There is a [ticket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/50248) raised in Gitlab-ce, who knows when it will be implemented.

Comment: EADDRINUSE means that you're trying to bind the service to a port that is already in use. Were you setting PORT twice in variables? You can't define the same key twice.

Comment: I meant that I am using `PORT` env variable in both current and `myprivaterepo` image and hence and error used to be thrown.

Comment: Ahh right so the env variable was being set globally rather than per run. Yeah that's not what I would have expected either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ticket mentioned in the accepted answer has been implemented.

It is now possible to specify variables that apply only to a specific service, like this:

```
test_job:
    stage: test

    services:
      - mongo:4.0.4
      - redis:5.0.1
      - name: registry.gitlab.com/myteam/myprivaterepo:latest
        alias: myprivaterepo
        variables:
          PORT: 9090
          APP_VAR: foobar

    variables:
      - MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/aics
      - REDIS_CLIENT_HOST: redis
      - PORT: 3000
      - SERVER_HOST: myprivaterepo
      - SERVER_PORT: 9090

    script: npm test
```

Service docs are available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/index.html#available-settings-for-services).