# Set environment variable for container of specific image of gitlab job

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab

I want to perform some analysis of source files in Gitlab-managed project. The analysis is about computing frequencies, counting unique strings etc. I came to conclusion that the plain bash `find`|`grep`|`sed`|`sort`|`uniq`-based solution would encounter its limits very soon. Hence I decided to use bash commands only to preprocess data into SQL table (created and filled in `create_table.sql` generated script - details of table are not substantial) and do subsequent analysis solely in SQL (`run_statistics.sql`) in own one-shot docker container.

I am trying to add this analysis as new job into Gitlab pipeline. It is sufficient for the result of the job to be some artifact with plain text output of SQL query dumps (no [reporting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsreports) needed at this moment). My intention is to run this job in [its own postgres docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-an-image) which [sees the project tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188996/653539).

```
statistics:
  image:
    name: postgres:16
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - chmod +x ./create_statistics_sql.sh
    - ./create_statistics_sql.sh > create_table.sql
    - psql -U postgres < create_table.sql
    - echo "<html><body><pre>" > statistics.html
    - psql -U postgres < run_statistics.sql >> statistics.html
    - echo "</pre></body></html>" >> statistics.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 7 days
    paths:
      - statistics.html
```

The problem is, the Postgres container requires setting of mandatory environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` (or `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust` since there is not security risk here, however the environment variable is needed anyway). Without it, the container for job won't start and then the error `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory` appears in job log.

In other words, I am looking for equivalent of `docker run -e` option for container spawned from job's `image:`. I tried to set it into `variables:` in job but without success. The `image:` section of job has very limited syntax, I would expect something like `image:docker:variable` though I am aware it is [not currently possible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#imagedocker).

Is there some workaround? (Actually I found one workaround in my self-answer but it is specific for my case and I am open to learn there is better solution.)

Notice: I don't (or intend to) use Postgres in project itself nor I have it as [service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837282/653539). (These two cases make my problem little bit hard to google.) I want to use it just as a single-use tool.

Comment: Why would the bash pipeline be hitting a limit?

Comment: I meant limit in complexity of querying logic. For example, `select value, count(*) from t group by value` in SQL is comparable with `sort | uniq -c` in bash and both is simple and comprehensible. While doing the `select value, count(*), string_agg(distinct other_column,', ')` or window functions in bash is lot harder and (at least to me) feels like wrongly selected tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution glued of hints in another SO answers.

- Postgres container must be spawned as a service (in `services:` section).
- Such service [can have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518809/653539) environment `variable:`s but - unfortunately - the `psql` command of that service is [not accessible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/index.html#using-software-provided-by-a-service-image) from job's script.
- Hence original Postgres container from image specified in `image:` section has to stay there too, it serves as Postgres client.
- The client connects to server using `alias` hostname (the `psql -h` option).

Whole solution:

```
statistics:
  image:
    name: postgres:16
  services:
    - name: postgres:16
      alias: postgresserver
      variables:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - chmod +x ./create_statistics_sql.sh
    - ./create_statistics_sql.sh > create_table.sql
    - psql -h postgresserver -U postgres < create_table.sql
    - echo "<html><body><pre>" > statistics.html
    - psql -h postgresserver -U postgres < run_statistics.sql >> statistics.html
    - echo "</pre></body></html>" >> statistics.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 7 days
    paths:
      - statistics.html
```

This is enough for me at this moment. Anyway I am curious if there exists simpler/more universal solution of passing environment variables directly into first container.